# UML and Implementation: Associating Classes through IDs

Tags: uml, aggregation, composition

I was recently studying an online course. it was recommended that to reduce coupling we could simply pass the ID from the customer object to the Order object. that way the Order did not have to have a full reference to the Customer class.

The idea certainly seems simple and why pass a whole object if you don't need all its attributes?

1) What do you think of this idea?
2) How would I express the relationship between the Customer class and the Order class in UML if only an ID is passed. This isn't just an example of aggregation is it? Doesn't composition and aggregation require more than just passing a value?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) What does the order need to do with the Customer object?
2) What are you using the UML for? Is it to document a domain model? Is it used to generate code?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to be clear about what UML actually is. On the one hand you have an *idea* and on the other side there is some *code* running on *hardware*. Ideally the latter supports the first in a way that brings added value to a user of the *idea*. Now, there are many possibilities to describe the *way* from *idea* to *code*. And UML is one of them. It is possible to describe each step on this *way* but for pragmatic reasons UML stops at the border of *code*, namely programming languages.

Now for you concrete question: Any object can be seen as an instance. That is some concrete memory partition with a fixed address. Programming languages realize instances by allocating memory and using the start address as reference. And since this reference does not change the object can be identified by its address. Clearly then, an association will just be the a pointer. And an association class will hold two (or more) such pointers.

Honestly, the very first time I started with OO I was also confused and thought that it's a waste of resource to pass those large objects. But since it's just a pointer it's really easy going.

Again, things can get more difficult if you need to persist objects. In that case you need an artificial key you can save along with the object and you will likely need tables to map artificial key to the concrete instance address.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on a number of factors, which I started listing in a comment attached to your question. I will assume that you are either using UML to create a Domain Model, or you are describing an implementation done using a statically typed language.

If you are using UML to create a Domain Model, you are obfuscating the semantics when you use an ID to "link" classes. Just draw and annotate the association and you're done.

If you are describing an implementation done using a statically typed language -  *types exist for a reason*. Using generic IDs to link things means that the information that the system needs most become more indirect, and therefore more opaque (which is bad). In your case, the Order object still must acquire a typed reference to a Customer object to do anything with it.

For example, the Order may acquire a reference to the Customer by invoking a lookup by the ID, but *it must cast the reference to an appropriate type* to invoke anything on the Customer object. So you haven't reduced the coupling from the Order to the Customer. You just buried it somwhere else.